# complex row structure with data table search jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to use data-table jquery to implement search functionality on of our asp.net page.

I have one row in header template and 2 rows in item template. First row means company name and second row has repeater which creates multiple project rows.

what I am trying to achieve here is that the search textbox should search company name or project name.
But it is giving an error "Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 1".

The plugin works if I use only one row in Item Template which is company name.

I really appreciate your suggestions.

Following is my code:

```
                        <div class="panel panel-default">

                           <div class="panel-body sorting-img">
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="No Data Found">          </asp:Literal>
                                <div class="table-responsive" id="tabResponsive">
                                <asp:Repeater  runat="server" OnItemDataBound ="rptCompanyList_ItemDataBound" >
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="center">
                                                <div class="clientTable">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <%--<input type="checkbox" class="flat-grey">--%>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDataAll" CssClass="flat-grey" 
                                                         AutoPostBack="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkDataAll_CheckedChanged"
                                                    runat="server" />
                                                    </label>
                                                &nbsp;</div></th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Name
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Created Date
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Account Rep
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        % Storage (Used|Available)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Status
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead><tbody>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                            <tr class="clientTr">
                                                <td class="center">
                                                <div class="clientTable">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <%--<input type="checkbox" class="flat-grey">
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkData" CssClass="flat-grey" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                                        OnCheckedChanged="chkData_CheckedChanged"
                                                    runat="server" />--%>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkData" CssClass="flat-grey" OnCheckedChanged="chkData_CheckedChanged"
                                                    AutoPostBack="false"  runat="server" />

                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfAccountID" runat="server" />
                                                    </label>
                                                &nbsp;</div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <!-- //220814_02 -->
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                    <a  class="fc_red  pull-left" runat="server" >
                                                        Edit
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltCreateDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltAccRepName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="proClientBackground">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltAccountStatus" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptProjectListCompanyWise" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptProjectListCompanyWise_ItemDataBound">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <!-- //080814_01 -->
                                                        <td align="center">                                                      
                                                            <%--<img id="imgProject" src="../Images/note_ico.jpg" />--%>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkData" CssClass="flat-grey" OnCheckedChanged="chkData_CheckedChanged"
                                                                AutoPostBack="false" onclick='getProjectID(this);' runat="server" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <!-- //080814_01 -->
                                                        <td class="projectTD" valign="middle">

                                                            <a id="ancManageDocument" class="fc_red" runat="server" href="#">
                                                                <asp:Literal ID="ltProjectName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                            </a>

                                                         </td>


                                                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                                            <asp:Literal ID="ltCreateDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                                            <asp:Literal ID="ltAccRepName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="tdProgress" align="center" valign="middle">
                                                            <div class="proClientStorage">
                                                            <div class="progress progressAdminClient">
                                                              <div id="divProgressBar" runat="server" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >

                                                              </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                                            <asp:Literal ID="ltAccountStatus" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </tr>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="AllSelectedProjectIDs" runat="server" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a JSFIDDLE?

Comment: Could you add the jquery code as well?